# Flutter ThemeData is not working for the Text

Tags: dart, flutter

Code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Theme(
    data: ThemeData(textTheme: TextTheme(body1: TextStyle(fontSize: 40))),
    child: Text("Hello World!"), // size not changing
  );
}
```

But when I use

```
data: ThemeData(textTheme: TextTheme(body1: TextStyle(fontSize: 40))),
```

in my `MaterialApp`'s `theme` then size of the `Text` gets changed.

---

**PS**: I know I can give `Text` a size by using `style:` property but I wanna know why my code isn't changing `Text` font size.

Comment: but why would it use `body1`? why not `body2` for example? or any other `TextStyle`?

Comment: @pskink I tried it using `body1` and it worked (when theme is applied in the `MaterialApp`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Text](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) does not use [Theme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html). [Theme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) is material design specific, while [Text](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) is general purpose.

What [Text](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) uses is [DefaultTextStyle](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html), which is edited by `MaterialApp` (or some other widgets such as `AppBar`) with values from the [Theme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html).

The following should work:

```
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
  child: Text("Hello World"),
);
```